# Popping upper layers in keras

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

Suppose I have the following pretrained model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu', input_dim=5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

When I run it through the following data (X), I get the shape as expected:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(20, 5)
model.predict(X).shape
```

giving the shape (20,1)

However, for **transfer learning purposes** I wish to pop the top layer and run it through the same data.

```
model.layers.pop()
model.summary()
>>>
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 18        
=================================================================
Total params: 18
Trainable params: 18
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Looking at `model.summary()` after `model.layers.pop()` seems to have popped off the top layer. However, running `model.predict(X).shape` still results in a `(20,1)` shape and not `(20,3)` as expected.

**Question**: How am I supposed to correctly `pop` off the last few layers. This is an artificial example. In my case I need to delete the last 3 layers.

Comment: you should do `model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]`  and `model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []`after popping the 3 layers. Here you have a related issue: `https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2371`

Comment: I'm afraid this still outputs the shape (20,1) for `model.predict(X).shape`. I'm using Keras 2.0.5 if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8909

The following is the answer that is needed. A second model had to be created unfortunately, and for some reason @Eric's answer doesn't seem to work anymore as suggested in the other github issue.

```
model.layers.pop()
model2 = Model(model.input, model.layers[-1].output)
model2.predict(X).shape
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    loaded_model = keras.models.load_model(fname)

    # remove the last 2 layers
    sliced_loaded_model = Sequential(loaded_model.layers[:-2])

    # set trainable=Fasle for the layers from loaded_model
    for layer in sliced_loaded_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    # add new layers
    sliced_loaded_model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))  # trainable=True is default
    sliced_loaded_model.add(Dense(1))

    # compile
    sliced_loaded_model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=[])

    # fit
    ...
```

Simply, you can reconstruct the Sequential model